# Can the same value be bound more than once in a query?

Tags: sql, perl

There seems to be something of an (anti?) pattern in using bind parameters like this:

```
$dbh->do(
       'select foo from bar where baz > ? and baz < ? + 1',
       undef,
       $var1, $var1
)
```

i.e. what's really wanted is to use the value of `$var1` twice in the query.  Is there a way to avoid specifying `$var1` twice in the bind parameters list?

Answer (score 3):

First, the usage is actually

```
$dbh->do(
       'select foo from bar where baz > ? and baz < ? + 1',
       undef,
       $var1, $var1
);
```

Unless your DBD supports [positional or named placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aPg#Placeholders),

```
$dbh->do(
       'select foo from bar where baz > $1 and baz < $1 + 1',
       undef,
       $var1
);
```

you'll need to specify it twice, though you could use

```
$dbh->do(
       'select foo from bar where baz > ? and baz < ? + 1',
       undef,
       ($var1)x2
);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use numbered placeholders, if your driver supports them, like:

```
$dbh->do(
       'select foo from bar where baz > ?1 and baz < ?1 + 1',
       undef,
       $var1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use a named parameter. Certain libraries like [PDO support this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).